# Changing default directory and default html page for IIS through Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am looking to use Powershell to programatically change the default directory (and the home page - a simple static html) of IIS. For example, I created a new Drive 'D:\' and placed an 'index.html' and I would like IIS to launch this html instead of "C:\inetpub\www\iisstart.htm".

I can do this switch manually by RDP'ing into the machine but I need to achieve this using Powershell.

I am not sure if this is the way to do it but I tried this:

`Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\' -name physicalPath -value "D:\"`

The command doesn't throw any error but I get 500 - Internal server error.

If I check using another command as below, I get this displayed. But when I type the public IP of this machine the earlier page displaying content of `C:\inetpub\www\iisstart.htm` vanishes and I get 500 server error.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator>  Get-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Started    D:\                            http *:80:
```

I am pretty sure there must be a very simple way to do this but I couldn't find out what it is, in spite of hunting for hours together. Your help would be much appreciated!

Please note I am only trying to host this simple static html page for now (and nothing more).

Comment: As far as i know, 500 means the servr internal error. This means the powershell command you have used is right.There are some issue which is realted with your application hosted on the D disk or config issue. I suggest you could post more details information about your error message.

Comment: I finally managed to get it working. I used `Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site" -name physicalPath -value "D:"` which seem to work **but only after** I issue ` 'Get-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'`. When I was reading about Set-ItemProperty there is no ref to Get-Website.. But I found it strange that if i directly execute the Set-ItemProperty it would throw all sorts of errors (sometime wont throw error but nothing happens). But if i execute the Get-Website first and then issue Set-Itemproperty it works fine. Any comments on this sequence would help me understand how it worked.